# Error with task and authresult when trying to set up firebase login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following all the set up instructions here: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-cloud-backend-for-your-android-app-using-firebase/

but as soon as I try to implement the sign in, I get errors [here are all the places that I'm getting errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibsMz.png)

all of the errors just say "Cannot resolve symbol". I have tried looking up the problem and everywhere it just says to rebuild or clean the project and I've done that but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnCompleteListener` should use type `AuthResult` instead of `authResult`: `OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>`.

And `task` parameter should be this: `Task<AuthResult> task`.

For future questions, it is better to post the code instead of an image of the code.  That allows us to copy it into an answer.

Comment: @Justine If this answer has resolved your post, you should go ahead and accept it as the correct answer. :)